# Open NetCDF file including multiple variables using raster package

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, netcdf

I wanna open multiple NetCDF files including two variables by raster package, and then use my shapefile (polygon) to extract data and calculate the area average value. 
When I do this, a warning message showed up no matter using rater function or stack function. The content of the warning message is:

*Warning message:
In .varName(nc, varname, warn = warn) : varname used is: PEVAP
If that is not correct, you can set it to one of: PEVAP, APCP*

It looks like raster cannot open the NetCDF file including multiple variables.
Could anyone help me?
I am appreciated if you can additionally tell me how to calculate area average values using a shapefile.
Here are the data links.

```
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ltcEmxJ33iudX3lJTCM7B0zgeht9lPFX][1]
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b7tNdJHq_HZcw7NPz1kbVFDWli1G9zaJ][2]
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oC2kxVhC9MMcmz-IcIZJFkS6_tRKyIAM][3]
```

My code:

```
 rm(list=ls())
 library(raster)
 library(ncdf4)
 path       <- "E:/rrshp/"
 pathdata   <- "E:/data/"
 pathshp    <- "E:/test_shape"
 setwd(path)
 ncname     <-  list.files(pathdata,full.names=T)
 ## warning comes from the following code
 myrast     <-  raster(ncname[1]) 
 allrast    <-  stack(ncname)
```

Comment: Please post the text of the message, not a picture of the message.

Answer (score 0):

The error is shown because you have not specified the variable/s to be imported to raster. Try this:

```
#Check the variables available for ncname[1]
nc<-nc_open(ncname[1])
names(nc[['var']])
[1] "var1" "var2"      "var3"

#If I want to import "var1" and "var3" for ncname[1]
s<-stack(stack(ncname[1],varname="var1"),stack(ncname[1],varname="var3"))
```